# Mocking a ListState in Apache Flink 1.4

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am writing some test code for a `processElement` function in Apache Flink 1.4:

```
public class ProcessFunctionClass {

    public void processElement(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2,  Context context, Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> collector) {

        // if the state is empty, start a timer
        if (listState.get().iterator().hasNext() == false)
            context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(1000);

        listState.add("someStringToBeStored");

        // ...
    }

}
```

```
public class ProcessFunctionClassTest {

    private ProcessFunctionClass processFunctionClass;

    @Mock
    private ListState<String> listState;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        processFunctionClass = new ProcessFunctionClass();
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessElement() {

        ListState mockListState = mock(ListState.class);
        Iterable mockIterable = mock(Iterable.class);
        Iterator mockIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(tDPListState.get()).thenReturn(mockIterable);
        when(tDPListState.get().iterator()).thenReturn(mockIterator);
        when(tDPListState.get().iterator().hasNext()).thenReturn(false);

        processFunctionClass.processElement(tuple2, context, collector);

        // verify(...)
    }
}
```

When I debug using my IDE, just before I step into the `processElement()` method, `listState` is not `null` and appears to have been mocked successfully, but as soon as I get to `listState.get().iterator().hasNext()`, `listState` is `null` and I get a NullPointerException. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For implementing unit tests for a `ProcessFunction`, you may find it interesting to use the test harnesses created for this purpose. See [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html#unit-testing-stateful-or-timely-udfs--custom-operators) for details and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ProcessFunctionClass` you have a private `listState` variable.
In your test you create a completely unrelated `mockListState` variable and set some expectations on it.

For your test to work, you must provide a way (constructor or setter) to set `ProcessFunctionClass.listState` to desired value (your mocked list state)

On top of that, `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` seems to do nothing in your example: you haven't shown us any fields annotated with `@Mock` or `@InjectMocks`

**Update**

You are misusing `@Mock` annotation.
You should place it in the test class, not in class under test.
When placed in the test class, after a call to initMocks, the filed will be initialized with a mock of an appropriate type.

What you should fo instead:

- remove `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`, you are creating all the mocks manually.
- add a constructor in `ProcessFunctionClass`

```
public ProcessFunctionClass(ListState<String> listState) {
    this.listState = listState
}
```

- use this constructor in your test

```
var mockListState = mock(ListState.class);
var processFunctionClass = new ProcessFunctionClass();
```

Comment: I edited my code to add that Mock annotation (it was already in my code). As for using a setter or constructor, can you give an example? I don't see in the API docs that using one is necessary. I'm not using a setter in my main code? Is there a difference?

Comment: I had the mock variable in my test class indeed. Here I put it in the main class by mistake.